# Suppose you have a decimal -12 what is the signed 4 bit representaion of it

Tags: bit, short, truncation

Suppose you have decimal -12 what is the signed 4 bit representaion of it.

basically -12 = 1 0100 how can i convert this to 4 bit

Answer (score 1):

4-bit twos-complement integers range from -8 (1000) to +7 (0111); there is no representation of -12. You need 5 or more bits for that.